# Windows 7 File Recovery. Can I store other things in my external hard drive?

Tags: windows, backup

So here's my question: I created a backup system image for my Win 8 PC using the Windows 7 File Recovery feature. I created a 40gig image and I stored it in a 500 gig HD. Is it possible that I can still use the HD normally, and use the backup images just fine? Will there be any conflicts when I try to restore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the external drive wasn't converted to a bootable drive there should not be any conflicts if you continue to use your external hard drive as normal. Try not to move the image around and you should be fine. Source: I have about 10 images on my external hard drive along with many other files and haven't encountered an issue

Comment: Followup. The same applies to System Backup that also includes all files and system image, right?